# C++ Allegro 5 - rescaling images in initializizion

Tags: allegro5

How to resize initialized image with allegro5 in initializition part of game?

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *player = NULL;
player = al_load_bitmap("st.png");
//something
al_draw_bitmap(player, player_position_x, player_position_y, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `al_draw_bitmap()` use:

```
void al_draw_scaled_bitmap(ALLEGRO_BITMAP *bitmap,
   float sx, float sy, float sw, float sh,
   float dx, float dy, float dw, float dh, int flags);
```